# The rights to move the computers inside the OU without the ability to delete they from the AD

Tags: active-directory, user-permissions

But... How can I do this?

Even if I forbid deleting the computer object directly, the user can still delete the unit.
If it is possible to prohibit deleting the computer, then we cannot move from folder to folder and subfolders.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This right does not exist; moving a computer to a sibling OU, a child OU a parent OU, a different OU or container, specifically *requires* the delete computer object permission.

[image: Breakdown of Permissions required to move a computer object]

As documented here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20747.delegate-moving-user-group-and-computer-accounts-between-organizational-units-in-active-directory.aspx

Comment: Of course, it's a pity that this is so.
Thank you for saving my time!